# Trouble with fixed Navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want my Navigation bar to be placed at the very top of my website and have a fixed position,  and I want my container div to be 40px down from the navigation bar. But the Navigation bar keeps getting pushed from the top. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `top:0` in your #nav CSS

Comment: I would also change your `margin-top` to `60px;`

Answer (score 1):

Set top attribute:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    TOP: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/10/). I changed #nav to have

```
top: 0;
```

And #container to have

```
margin-top: 90px;
```

Your nav bar is 50px, so 40px down would be 90px total.